# Entity Framework - Last ID of Entree

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

Currently I am programming an application which saves and deletes entries in a database (code first with entity framework). My question is how can I get the next database id (configured with auto increment - so it added automatically +1).

I tried something like:

```
var a = databaseContext.MyObject.LastOrDefault().Id;
var myNextDatabaseId = a+1;
```

This pseudo code is working for most of the cases. But if i had 5 entrees in my database and delete all the five entree's my next database-counter would be **6**. When i'm using the code above it will return "null" becouse there is really no entree. But i must get the next database auto increment id.

Is there a possibility which doesn't create a new database entry? Think this shouldn't be necessary.

For example following data construct:

1. Inserted entry one (internal id = 1)
2. Inserted entry two (internal id = 2)
3. Delete entry one
4. Delete entry two
5. Read last database entry (entry = null). All data was deleted but I am trying to receive the next auto-increment id **3**

Comment: why do you need the next database id? if its auto increment, only your database should care about the id it's going to give. If you actually need to get it, you'll have to ask the database. The query for this is different depending on your dbs, on SQL express its SELECT IDENT_CURRENT(TableName). Also, notice the spelling is "Entry", not "Entree".

Comment: @DevilSuichiro i am useing an external webservice which requires this identifier. if the webservice returns a http code 200 for this id i will persist the entree in the database. otherwise i don't wanna create a database entree. i know that this is bad system design, but it is defined like it is

Answer (score 0):

Use an explicit transaction scope and identity column. Trying to maintain IDs at the application level isn't scale-able and will be prone to concurrency errors.

Ideally the transaction should span the web service call to roll back automatically if the call fails. With an explicit transaction you can call your `context.SaveChanges()` which will expose the next ID assigned to the entity, and then roll back if the web service call fails. This can be a transaction managed by the context or `TransactionScope`.

see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn456843(v=vs.113).aspx